# How to split a comma separated string that contains substrings within parentheses with commas

Tags: java

Here is my example:

Input:

```
String str="hello,there,(what,is,new),today,(with,you)"
```

Desired output:

```
hello
there
(what,is,new)
today
(with,you)
```

Comment: Show your attempts to achieve the goal first.

Comment: String str="hello,there,(what,is,new),today,(with,you)";
     String[] tokens = str.split("\\((?!=[^\\(*\\)$)])");      
     for(String t : tokens) {
         System.out.println("> "+t);
     }

Comment: > hello,there,
> what,is,new),today,
> with,you)

Comment: This is my latest try:<br><br>String str="hello,there,(what,is,new),today,(with,you)";<br><br>
      
    String[] tokens = str.split(",(?=[^\\(*\\)$)])");      
    for(String t : tokens) {
       System.out.println("> "+t);
     }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now it works

```
String str="hello,there,(what,is,new),today,(with,you)";
int inside = 0;
int index = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++){
    if (str.charAt(i) == ')'){
        inside--;
    }else if (str.charAt(i) == '('){
        inside++;
    }else if (str.charAt(i) == ',' && inside == 0){
        System.out.println(str.substring(index, i));
    index = i+1;
    }
}if (index != str.length()){
    System.out.println(str.substring(index, str.length()));
}
```

Comment: thanks. I tried it but didn't work. I was thinking more in terms of using regex.

Comment: Check it now. It's fixed and I believe it finally works.

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest would be to go through the string char by char in a for-loop and replace commas with spaces, unless you are inside parenthesis (you need to hold count of them)

Comment: The alternatives involve using a regular-expression library or a parser generator to execute a formalized version of the described operation.

Comment: well then i suggest replacing commas inside brackets first to some other symbol with a Regexp, after that replacing the normal commas with spaces, and then replacing the other symbol back to comma ^_^

Comment: I'm not disagreeing with you, just pointing out tools which could be used for this purpose if the OP has more complicated cases.

Comment: ah sure, sorry i thought that you commented on the allowed methods of solving the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
int index1=-1;
int index2=0;
for(int i=0;i< str.length;i++)
{
if(str.charAt(i) == ',')
   {
index2=i;
myList.add(str.substring(index1+1 ,index2-1));
index1=index2;
  }
}
```

Comment: are you storing substrings into myList? I am getting:
hell
ther
(wha
i
new
toda
(wit

Comment: for(int i=0;i<myList.size();i++)
system.our.println(myList.get(i));

Comment: thanks, but this doesn't produce the desired output.

Comment: i found it look what i wiil post

Comment: can you make it as solution because i store the result in a Lit not just print it

Answer (score 0):

```
String str="hello,there,(what,is,new),today,(with,you)";
ArrayList<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
int index1=-1;
int index2=0;
for(int i=0;i< str.length();i++)
{
if(str.charAt(i) != '(' ){
   if(str.charAt(i) == ',' )
     {
  index2=i;
  myList.add(str.substring(index1+1 ,index2));
  index1=index2;
  }
}
else
    while(str.charAt(i)!=')')
        i++;
}

for(int i=0;i<myList.size();i++) System.out.println(myList.get(i));
```